# Filter square brackets on Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I'm struggling to filter square brackets on my log messages in Kibana.
Suppose I have the messages:

```
[BOOK] The Book 32 was sold
Exception on buying BOOK
```

And I want to filter only messages having exactly `[BOOK]` (so I should get only the first one).

I have tried filtering free text with all kinds of escaping I could think of:

```
[BOOK]
"[BOOK]"
\[BOOK\]
"\[BOOK\]"
\\[BOOK\\]
```

And also tried filtering by the message field:

```
message: [BOOK]*
message: "[BOOK]*"
message: \[BOOK\]*
message: "\[BOOK\]*"
```

But Kibana seems to simply ignore the square brackets and always brings both messages, highlighting only the `BOOK` word.

How can I force it search for the `[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your `message` field is an analysed text, then the brackets are dropped by the analyzer. You should run your query against a keyword data type. More precisely, you will need to run a regexp against a keyword data type, such as a `prefix` or a `wildcard` query.

Let's assume that the mapping of `message` is `keyword`. If `[BOOK]` is always at the beginning of your log message, then a valid query is the following:

```
{ "query": {
  "prefix": {
    "message": "[BOOK]"
  }
}}
```

If instead you would like to search for `[BOOK]` in any part of the `message` value, then you would need something like:

```
{ "query": {
  "wildcard": {
    "message": "*[BOOK]*"
  }
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @glencota.
I understand very little about Kibana, so it didn't make much sense to me what you said n_n'. BUT, I found out that my kibana offers the field `message.keyword`. Using your query with this field worked! Thanks! :D

Comment: hi João, glad that works. However, what I wrote doesn't have much to do with Kibana (which is "just" a UI), but rather with Elasticsearch. If you are going to spend more time querying Elasticsearch, I *totally* recommend you to read about the notion of index mapping https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html